# Is using std::string instead of char* bad?

Tags: c++, string

I'm beginning with C++ and I am little confused whether to use `std::string` or `char*`.

Lets say I need to concatenate a few strings. I'd do it like this - I think it's the shortest way.

```
std::string data = "some data";
const char *result = std::string("start" + data + "end" + "something else").c_str();
```

Question is: Should I do it this way or use c-functions like `strcpy()`, `strcat()` etc.? Is using `std::string` slower, less effective than `char*`?

Thanks

Comment: That is no way related to C.

Comment: IMO you should use `std::string` everywhere if you're a beginner.

Comment: Indeed. Keep it Simple.

Comment: @Olaf Really? It's question about comparison of C++ string **and C** string.

Comment: The title is kinda funny. Who told you this?

Comment: @MartinHeralecký But it's a question about programming in C++. The legacy of the c-style string is irrelevant.

Comment: It is not. It is about using either in C++, so using C++ or C style programming **in C++**. In C the question does not apply because you don't have the option.

Comment: *"Is using std::string instead of char* bad?"* - 1995 has called and wants its C++ stereotypes back.

Comment: In C++ you should use `std::string` unless you have a **very** strong reason not to. Depending on what you are doing, it might sometimes be faster than C strings, and in any case it is *much* easier to use correctly. Being correct is always more important than being a nanosecond faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As many have already said in the comments, always use `std::string`. It is better than `null-terminated` strings (C / char* strings) in almost every way.

However the way you used string in your example is not correct and involves undefined behaviour.

```
const char *result = std::string("start" + data + "end" + "something else").c_str();
```

In this line you created a temporary `string`. As I hope you know, temporary variables only last until the end of the row (as far as this example goes at least). So after this row the `string` will not exist anymore. A `string` has an internal array on heap in which it stores its `string`. The function `string::c_str()` returns a pointer to the first character of that array. But because the string object gets destroyed at the end of the line, the pointer result will point to a deleted part of the memory and accessing it is undefined behaviour.

```
std::string data = "some data";
std::string bigData("start" + data + "end" + "something else");
const char *result = bigData.c_str();
```

If you wrote your code like this, then there is no undefined behaviour since `result`'s lifetime is shorter than the string `bigData`.

Comment: Plus one. Plus two if you also mention that `c_str` adds a null terminator if one is missing. Might tie in your first paragraph a little better if you do that.

Answer (score 9):

`const char *result = std::string("start" + data + "end" + "something else").c_str();` **is a recipe for disaster**.

The right hand of the assignment is using an anonymous temporary and will leave a dangling pointer `result`.

The idea of converting `std::string data = "some data";` to `char* data = "some data";` is not emphasising the fact that "some data", after the conversion from `std::string` becomes **read-only memory**. Modification of the memory to which `data` is pointing to is undefined behaviour. At least use a `const char*` so compilation will fail on such an attempt.

All these problems go away if you use `std::string`. There's your answer. It considerably simplifies things.

Comment: To be fair, OP has `const char* data = "some data"`, which I think is fine when the RHS is a literal.

Comment: OP is considering "use std::string or char*", which I've taken literally. I've clarified though.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. At the beginning you write that *std::string...* is bad and then that it's good. So what should I use?

Comment: No, `std::string` is a thing of beauty. Your problem only arises when you attempt to access its data buffer in order to extract a `const char*`.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer (and it is surely very good due to its upvotes). But I still don't get it. What's wrong with "accessing the data buffer in order to extract a const char*"?

Comment: @MartinHeralecký You create a temporary string and extract a pointer from it. When the temporary is destroyed (at the end of the full expression) that pointer will be invalid.